# Running C# with batch parameters

Tags: c#, batch-file

In java you can pass parameters to the program through batch. How can I do that in C#?

Like if I needed the program to receive a file name how can I get it to the program?

Comment: you could either use args in main method or you could use app.config

Comment: What are u going to do with batch?Do you want to redirect the output of the batch file to a C# program?

Comment: Removing the `[java]` tag as the answer won't have anything to do with Java.

Answer (score 3):

Supposing you have created a C# console application (exe), it will be created with a main static method that receives an array of strings. Those strings will be the arguments passed to the program.

For example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", args));
    }
}
```

If your console application is named "MyApp.exe", you could pass parameters is this way:

> MyApp.exe "first arg" second

And you should get this output:
[image: output]

Answer (score 2):

The Main() routine in your application receives an array of strings which contain the arguments which were passed in on the command line.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (string s in args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Outside of Main you can use `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`.

```
string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to read the output from *.bat files this will help you..`

```
Process  thisProcess = new Process();
thisProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
thisProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
thisProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Users\My User Name\Documents";
thisProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "ipconfig";
thisProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/h";
thisProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
thisProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
thisProcess.Start();
thisProcess.WaitForExit();
//Output from the batch file
string myOutput = thisProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```